# Why is this F# nested match expression not working correctly?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Right now, I have a nested pattern match that is behaving oddly.

Here is the code snippet

```
match setting with
| "-f" | "--file" ->            // Open file
    ({ state with file = Some (cur_dir + "\\" + elem) }, "")
| "" ->                         // Option without parameter
    match elem with
    | "-h" | "--help" ->        // Display help message
        ({ state with help = true }, "")
    | "-r" | "--readonly" ->    // Open with readonly
        ({ state with readonly = true }, "")
    | opt -> (state, opt)
| _ -> (state, "")              // Ignore invalid option
```

Unfortunately, I get two warnings when I compile the above code. One states that the final wildcard pattern is unreachable. The other states that the first match statement is incomplete.

These two warnings seem to be in conflict with each other, and if I add in parentheses to make the expression more clear, the warnings disappear and my code works correctly.

```
match setting with
| "-f" | "--file" ->            // Open file
    ({ state with file = Some (cur_dir + "\\" + elem) }, "")
| "" ->                         // Option without parameter
    ( match elem with
      | "-h" | "--help" ->        // Display help message
          ({ state with help = true }, "")
      | "-r" | "--readonly" ->    // Open with readonly
          ({ state with readonly = true }, "")
      | opt -> (state, opt) )
| _ -> (state, "")              // Ignore invalid option
```

My question is this: what was wrong with the original code? It was not a case of a misplaced parenthesis, and it seems like it should be obvious to the compiler where each match ends.

Edit: here's the complete function, in case it helps

```
let process_args argv =
    let (result, _) = ((default_settings, "-f"), argv) ||>
        Array.fold (fun (state, setting) elem ->
            match setting with
            | "-f" | "--file" ->            // Open file
                ({ state with file = Some (cur_dir + "\\" + elem) }, "")
            | "" ->                         // Option without parameter
                match elem with
                | "-h" | "--help" ->        // Display help message
                    ({ state with help = true }, "")
                | "-r" | "--readonly" ->    // Open with readonly
                    ({ state with readonly = true }, "")
                | opt -> (state, opt)
            | _ -> (state, "")              // Ignore invalid option
        ) in
    result
```

I should also note that this error occurs with both light and verbose syntax.

Edit2: I mistakenly pasted a slightly altered function, which resulted in some compilation errors instead of just warnings. My apologies.

Comment: Your example works fine for me. It's almost assuredly an indentation error.

Comment: The example was copied and pasted straight from the source code. Also, the error occurs regardless of whether or not I use `#light "off"`

Comment: When I copy your match statement into VS Code, the Ionide plugin shows me no warnings. But when I copy your full `process_args` function, I get an indentation error on the `let` statement. I'll write a full answer, but the short version (so you don't have to wait) is: move your `((default_settings, etc.` tuple down to the next line and indent it four spaces, and make no other changes, and your code should work.

Comment: btw, there is [Argu](https://fsprojects.github.io/Argu/) if you do a lot argument parsing.

Answer (score 4):

When I copy your full function into VS Code, I get two errors, both caused by the same indentation mistake:

```
let process_args argv =
    let (result, _) = ((default_settings, "-f"), argv)
        ||> Array.fold (fun (state, setting) elem ->
        // (snip rest of function)
```

The two errors are on the `let` of `let (result, _) = ...`, and on the `||>` operator. The error on `let` is:

> Incomplete value or function definition. If this is in an expression, the body of the expression must be indented to the same column as the 'let' keyword.

and the error on the `||>` is:

> Unexpected infix operator in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

Both of these errors are actually rather unhelpful in helping you figure out what went wrong, because the actual cause is a simple indentation mistake in your use of the `||>` operator.

According to the [F# code formatting guidelines](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md#pipeline-operators), the "pipe" operators (`|>`, `||>`, and so on) needs to be indented at the same level as the expression they're operating on. In your code, the `||>` operator is indented under the `(result, _)` tuple. But that tuple isn't actually what the `||>` is meant to be operating on; that tuple is the *target* of the assignment. The expression that `||>` is operating on is the `((default_settings, "-f"), argv)` tuple. So you should have indented your code like this:

```
let process_args argv =
    let (result, _) = ((default_settings, "-f"), argv)
                      ||> Array.fold (fun (state, setting) elem ->
                      // (snip rest of function)
```

Or else:

```
let process_args argv =
    let (result, _) =
        ((default_settings, "-f"), argv)
        ||> Array.fold (fun (state, setting) elem ->
        // (snip rest of function)
```

The second one is better, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That fixed the warning if light syntax is on. It still is giving the match warnings if light is off. Also, if the light syntax is on and the `||>` operator is on the same line as the let binding, it will give the match warning. This is such a puzzling warning...

Comment: I should also mention that I messed up and copied the wrong code into the original post. I did have the `||>` operator on the same line as the let binding in my code when I ran it and got the warnings. I do not know why I changed it. I will fix that. Sorry for the mistake!

Comment: If you're trying to write F# in verbose syntax (that is, with `#light "off"`), I think you'll find very few people who are familiar with the syntax's details any more. The light syntax has become the default and the de-facto standard for F# code. Unless you're doing something like copying and pasting code from another ML language and wanting it to work with minimal changes, I would **highly** recommend just learning F#'s light syntax.

Comment: Case in point: I've just spent 5-10 minutes hunting for ANY reference online about match expressions in verbose syntax, and how to terminate them. (Because, as you've already figured out, the compiler in verbose syntax is thinking that the final `_` case of the first match expression is actually part of the second match expression). I have found *no* references to tell me whether there's a better way than wrapping the second match expression in parentheses. As you said, "it seems like it should be obvious to the compiler where each match ends." Yes, it should -- **iff** you're in light syntax.

Comment: For all I know, you might have just uncovered a compiler bug that has gone unnoticed until now because nobody uses verbose syntax any longer. But whatever the reason, I'm not going to be able to find a way to fix your problem in verbose syntax mode. It works in light mode, and since light mode is the de-facto standard and that's the only thing anyone writes about on the Web anymore, that's all the help I'm going to be able to give you. Hopefully the "Just switch to light mode" advice won't make you have to rewrite TOO much code. It should be worth it in the long run.

Comment: You're right. Thank you so much for your help. I've been using verbose to try and force myself to use F# with a more functional style, since it makes most imperative code much more difficult/uglier to write.

Comment: I also, just now, thought of searching for the answer in terms of OCaml instead of F#. The answer that I have found there was simply to use parentheses. I guess most of the verbose "documentation" is just to search for the problem in terms of OCaml. Anyways, thank you!

Comment: @idlys: I feel you're somewhat misguided in your use of verbose syntax. There's nothing in it that would force you to write more functional F#. The only difference is in whether you use indentation or explicit keywords to delimit constructs.